# vertica error occurred during query preparation : no connection to the server

Tags: vertica

We are trying to run the insert statement , it shows below error :

ErrorMsg: [Vertica][VerticaDSII] (10) An error occurred during query preparation: no connection to the server

sometimes if i try running it again ,it gets executed successfully.
I have increased the resultbuffersize,and also maxmemorysize for my resource pool .

Let me know what is the core issue and action to resolve this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your connection is getting closed because of a timeout, and you are trying to use a closed connection. When using connection pooling, you need logic in your code that pulls the connection out of the pool to check to see if the connection is still open. If it isn't, it needs to be discarded and a new, open connection created and returned.

It's usually your DBMS that is disconnecting the connection after a specified timeout. You can configure the DBMS to not ever disconnect, but that's usually a bad idea since you could easily end up with connection leaks, and your server could run out of connections, causing all future connections to fail until the server is restarted.

Comment: I have increased the max memory size of my resource pool  to 40 %. Will It resolve ? Or should I check various other jobs which is been executed at the same time and schedule properly. Note : We are executing trunacte and some delete command also at the same time .

Comment: I don't think it's a memory size issue. You need to change how your code handles closed connections that are pulled from the connection pool. What language are you using for your app?